# If $E_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Euler number, show that $E_{4n}$ is divisible by 5.

Tags: number-theory

This is one part of a problem I have been working on for homework.  In a previous part, I have established the recurrence relation

$$ E_n = - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i = 1}^n \binom{n}{i} E_{n - i} (1 + (-1)^i); \quad E_0 = 1. $$

I was thinking now that I should use some sort of induction.  I found that $E_4 = 5$.  Now suppose $E_{4(n-1)}$ is divisible by 5 for some integer $n \geq 2$.  Then from the above recurrence relation, I can write

$$ E_{4n} = - \frac{1}{2} \left( 2 \binom{4n}{2} E_{4n - 2} + 2 \binom{4n}{4} E_{4n - 4} \right) + E_{4(n-1)}. $$
By induction, $E_{4(n-1)}$ is divisible by 5.  But I am stuck on how to show $- \left( \binom{4n}{2} E_{4n - 2} + \binom{4n}{4} E_{4n - 4} \right)$ is divisible by 5.

Comment: I assume you noticed that $E_{4n-4}=E_{4(n-1)}$.  So it remains to show that $5|{4n \choose 2}E_{4n-2}$.  Or am I misreading your middle statement?  Also, are you allowed to use strong induction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be approached in a simple way.
Since we know that the values of the derivatives in $0$ of the function
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{\cosh(t)} $$
are integer numbers (Euler numbers), we can focus on a differential equation satisfied by $f(x)$:
$$ f^{(IV)} = f - 20 f^3 + 24 f^5, $$
and get:
$$ (\heartsuit)\quad f^{(IV)} \equiv  f-f^5 \pmod{5}. $$
By evaluating in $0$ we immediately have $E_{4}\equiv 0\pmod{5}$.

But since for any $f$ with integer derivatives 
$$ \frac{d^4}{dx^4}f^5 \equiv 0\pmod{5}$$
holds, by deriving four times both members of $(\heartsuit)$ we get:
$$ E_{4n} = f^{(4n)}(0) \equiv f^{(IV)}(0) \equiv E_4 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}, $$
QED.

Comment: What is $f^{(IV)}$?  Is this the same thing as $f^{(4)}$, the fourth derivative of $f$?  Also, where did that differential equation come from?

Comment: Yes, $f^{(IV)}$ is the fourth derivative of $f$, and the differential equation comes from the explicit computation of it.